# change url or query string wihout reloading using jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-plugins

I want to change the url or query string without reloading the page...

I have used the [QUERY STRING OBJECT](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) plugin for jquery

I have this [example page](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/newAlbum.jsp?uid=14#aid=26)
in which on click of a album it should change the query string...

Now i can change the url using the code

```
window.location.href =  $.query.set('aid', a_id);
```

but it goes for reloading the page...

and this code does not have any effect

```
 var newUrl =  $.query.set('aid', a_id);
```

How can do without reloading the page...

how can i do without reloading the page...

Thanks 
Pradyut 
India

Comment: What you're asking to do doesn't make sense.  You cannot change the address in the browser's address bar without reloading the page.  Changing the query string changes the address and necessarily requires the page to reload the new address.

Comment: This does make sense.  He's looking for the hash property, as explained here: http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution...

change the query string after a #

you can get and set the query string using javascript

```
location.hash = 'something=anything'
```

Thanks
Pradyut
India

Comment: I don't understand - how does this help you?  You aren't changing the querystring - you're changing the anchor.

Comment: read hash with the above javascript, modify dom elements with js calling ajax data...

Comment: this isnt changing the query string it is changing the anchor

Answer (score 7):

You cannot change the query string without reloading the page.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is a difference between query and fragment as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the Hash, your approved solution might work ok. However, to modify the query you will need to use the history.pushState. It works only on web browsers with the HTML5 History API, though.

```
if (history.pushState) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?myNewUrlQuery=1';
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
```

I tested, and it worked fine. It does not reload the page, but it only allows you to change the URL query. You would not be able to change the protocol or the host values.

For more information:

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which you may find useful is the BBQ plugin for jQuery.  Here's an example:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/